# Pure Css Center binary tree

Tags: html, css

I am using [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/9zftw6o1/7/) html and css for display binary tree in my application.

everything works fine but i want to add the left and right class for the `<a href=""></a>` so child display to left having class left and same as for right class.

I try the following css but its not working.

```
.tree li a.left{
    text-align: left;
}
.tree li a.right{
    text-align: right;
}
```

can anyone suggest me where i have to change in  css so everything work perfectly.

Comment: You need to reorder your markup. With your current CSS, you are just aligning the text inside the list item.

Comment: @ManojKumar Can you create the fiddle for that?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9zftw6o1/8/ I just inserted 1004 before the 1005 list item.

Comment: I also try `float` but nothing working.

Comment: Nothing will work until you change the markup. The binary tree structure is so complex already.

Comment: @ManojKumar No i can't do that beacuse html creat dynamically from json thats why i have to use css for that

Comment: If you can use jQuery, use http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/ after the element is created.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87637/discussion-between-gaurang-ghinaiya-and-manoj-kumar).